# Unable to Display Image in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am unable to show images from database in gridview. I am able to save them. When i try to retrieve it doesnt show any thing but just a product name.

Here is my GridView.

```
<Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
         <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField = "ProductImagesID"
            DataImageUrlFormatString = "../ImageHandler.ashx?ProductImagesID={0}"
            ControlStyle-Width = "75" ControlStyle-Height = "75"
            HeaderText = "Preview Image">
                <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:ImageField>
    </Columns>
```

Image Handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Byte[] productImage;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["ProductImageId"] != null)
        {
            int productImageId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ProductImageId"]);

            productImage = ProductImageBL.GetImage(productImageId);

            if (productImage != null)
            {
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(productImage);
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

ProductImageBL GetImage Method:

```
public static Byte[] GetImage(int productImageId)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select ProductImage from ProductImages where ProductImageId = @ProductImageId";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductImageId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productImageId;

        SqlDataReader dataReader = DbUtility.GetDataReader(cmd);
        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            dataReader.Read();
            return (Byte[])dataReader[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Kindly, help me with this code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the _relevant_ sections of your code. This community does not take kindly to external links to code, and your question is much more likely to receive answers if you provide code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a page for image purpose say `GetMeImage.aspx` with function as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ProductImagesID"] != null)
    {
string query = "Select ProductImage from ProductImages where ProductImageId = @ProductImageId";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,YourConnectionObject);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductImageId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ProductImagesID"]);

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    if (dt != null)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
        + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
}
```

**In gridview** add template field

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField = "ProductImagesID"
            DataImageUrlFormatString = "../GetMeImage.aspx?ProductImagesID={0}"
            ControlStyle-Width = "75" ControlStyle-Height = "75"
            HeaderText = "Preview Image">
                <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:ImageField>
```